# How to split vector by zeros in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, split

I have got a problem with splitting a vector by zeros.

I have a vector for example

> v=[1 3 2 6 4 0 0 2 4 6 0 0 0 3 1]

I need to get vectors like

> v1=[1 3 2 6 4]
>
> v2=[2 4 6]
>
> v3=[3 1]

Is there any way to do this by using MATLAB functions?

Of course I don't know of how many subvectors are included in main vector *v* and how many zeros delimits vectors.

I'm not a programmer and also I'm not a pro in MATLAB.
I know a procedural way to do this but want do it by MATLAB somehow.

I found a function A = strsplit(str,delimiter) but I don't have string I have a vector.
So I searched for conversion function. I found S = char(V) but when I executed it it crashed.

Comment: crashed you mean you had an error? Post the error please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to have the output as a cell array, not as separate variables. That way the output will be easier to handle.

Try this:

```
v = [1 3 2 6 4 0 0 2 4 6 0 0 0 3 1]; %// data
w = [false v~=0 false]; %// "close" v with zeros, and transform to logical
starts = find(w(2:end) & ~w(1:end-1)); %// find starts of runs of non-zeros
ends = find(~w(2:end) & w(1:end-1))-1; %// find ends of runs of non-zeros
result = arrayfun(@(s,e) v(s:e), starts, ends, 'uniformout', false); %// build result
```

Result (for your example):

```
>> result{:}
ans =
     1     3     2     6     4
ans =
     2     4     6
ans =
     3     1
```

Comment: better than @oleg-komarov 's answer as this is general, Oleg's only works for integers 1-9, not 10 and above and not floating point values

Answer (score 2):

The `strsplit()` solution for a vector of **whole** numbers smaller than 9 (so a very specific solution, for a general solution see [Luis Mendo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076719/2180721)). Split and convert back to number:

```
res = strsplit(char(v), char(0));
res = cellfun(@(x) x - 0,res,'un',0);

celldisp(res)
res{1} =
     1     3     2     6     4
res{2} =
     2     4     6
res{3} =
     3     1
```

Comment: You have to be careful however, this will only work having integer vectors. Floating point entries will be truncated to integers.